# How to upgrade dojo1.2 to dojo1.7

Tags: dojo

I have an application which is running with dojo 1.2 having support for InternetExplorer8 only

so my problem is that I want to upgrate dojo version to 1.7 and InternetExplorer9/otherborwsers compatible,

so which API do I need to change? I am using all three dojo,dijit,dojox.

is there any solution or not ?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

There has been so many changes that I do not even know where to start...
You will probably have to rewrite a lot of code, but it is, I guess, a necessary pain to get to something much better.
You might want to write on some paper your custom widgets architectures, what they use etc, then try rewriting them in AMD with dojo1.7 or dojo 1.8 rc1
I would recommand a complete rewrite (not necessarily a complete rethink though).
Dojo 1.7+ are way much better than 1.2 in perfs, size, widgets available, power and flexibility, it is totally worth it.